# Keeping ListFragments in a FragmentPager in sync

Tags: android, android-fragments, consistency

Let's say I have a list of homogenous items which is likely to be changed in the lifetime of my Activity by user interaction or OS events. The `Activity` contains a `FragmentPager` which shows a number of `ListFragment`s.

These fragments share the previously mentioned data but display it in different ways. E.g. they differ in sorting order or display only a subset of the data. Currently each fragment keeps a separate list containing the respective part of the data in the respective order.

When the data changes, basicly every fragment has to be updated. This means resorting or adding/removing items from some of the fragments. **What is the best practice to keep the data in the different fragments consistent?**

Currently I have some sort of an observer object, which is notified when *something* changes and subsequently notifies the connected fragments. But there are a couple of problems:

- When the app just started, some of the fragments haven't been created by the FragmentPager, so notifying them is impossible.
- When swiping through the fragments some of them get paused. In this state, they can't update their list. Should they disconnect from the observer in this case? This leads to:
- When a change happens, while a fragment is disconnected, it basicly misses it.
- And so on...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your `ViewPager` shows the same data (or it's portion) but in different views. So, I belive `ViewPager` shouldn't act in any way when data is changed, it's responsibility of Adapter.

About points below you said:
a) creating of fragments inside `ViewPager` can be managed by you. Just see javadoc of `ViewPager::setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)` method.
b) I think you should do nothing with UI when data changed but fragment is in paused state. If you want to update do it in onResume(). Or better to set some field in DB (if you have) to "updates present" state and check it when `Activity`(`Fragment`) appears.
c) As in previous option - if fragment disconnected just ignore updates. Or if you really interested in that update use sticky `BroadcastReciver` (be carefull sticky BR is expensive thing)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your data in Application class, update only visible fragments when data has changed, and always ask for the new data in Fragment's onResume(), that'll do it

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is have each `ListFragment` use a `Loader` to load its data. Then, instead of having the observer notify the `Fragment` (which might have been killed) to refresh its data, register an observer for each `Loader` so that it will know when the data source has changed, and will re-query when one has been detected. (If your data source is an SQLite database and you are using a `ContentProvider`, the `CursorLoader` will do all of this for you).

This is the implementation I would recommend because

1. Each `Fragment`s behavior remains self-contained (i.e. each is a re-usable component that is not tied to any specific `ViewPager` or `Activity`).
2. It avoids the complexities of having to deal with potentially destroyed `Fragment`s within your `ViewPager`.

If you need a quick fix, you could probably get away with forcing the `Fragment`s to remain in memory using `ViewPager#setOffScreenPageLimit(int limit)` as Ivan suggests... however, this isn't as clean of a solution in my opinion.